# Chi square and t test error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I need to process some data and have written these short python scripts. However when I attempt to run them i receive this error: SyntaxError: can't assign to operator. Here is the code for both the chi square test and the t test.

chi square test:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
a = [5851, 72007]
b = [6927, 70802]
c = [5915, 71729]
d = [5660, 71491]
obs = [a, b, c, d]
chi2, p-value, dof, expected = stats.chi2_contingency(obs)
print 'p-value =', p-value
```

t test:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
a = [625, 480, 621, 633]
b = [647, 503, 559, 586]
t-statistic, p-value = stats.ttest_ind(a,b)
print 'p-value =', p-value
```

Comment: Wild guess: avoid the '-' in the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `-` in `p-value` makes the interpreter think there's an operator `-` in there. Change it to something like `p_value` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers using a ',' for assignment to the two variables doesn't work.

`t_statistic, p_value = stats.ttest_ind(a,b)` would cause an error. To prevent this use:

`t_statistic = p_value = stats.ttest_ind(a,b)` instead.